# Автогенерация URL для вывода отфильтрованых моделей

Tags: python, django, url

Изучаю Django и столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть две связанные через ForeignKey модели - Проект и Задача проекта. Хочу сделать что бы при выборе проекта открывалась страница со всеми заданиями, которые связаны с этим проектом.

Для этого:

прописал URL шаблон

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about-us', views.about, name='about'),
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('createProject', views.createProject, name='createProject'),
    path('<project/<int:projectID>/>', views.project_archieve, name='project_archieve'),
]
```

Все Проекты показаны в виде ссылок, которые должны вернуть нужный ID

```
{% if projects %}
    {% for el in projects %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning mt-2">
            <a href="{% url 'project_archieve' el.id %}">{{ el.id }} Project</a>
            <h3>{{ el.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ el.description }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Это всё обрабатывается в views.py

```
def project_archieve(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(project=request)
    return render(request, 'main/projectView.html', {'title': 'Просмотр проекта', 'tasks': tasks})
```

И выводится на отдельный html, что повторяет второй код.

Задумка не работает, по этому прошу помочь с решением!

Comment: Попробуйте не фильтровать задачи по проекту, а обратиться к проекту и по нему получить связанные экземпляры задач.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в своём вопросе.
Всё что нужно было сделать - передавать в views.py помимо request такой же аргумент, какой ловится в urls.py и уже этим аргументом фильтровать нужные модели.

urls.py

```
path('<int:project_id>/', views.project_archieve, name='project-archieve')
```

views.py

```
def project_archieve(request, project_id):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(project=project_id)
    return render(request, 'main/projectView.html', {'title': 'Просмотр проекта', 'tasks': tasks})
```